# Html and css Trying to put image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to put image to above of my video but it won't show up, only little mark top of the left side ? I know this is maybe simple but I don't get it.Maybe add something to css and change that images code place ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>    </TITLE>

<LINK href="to.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id="header">
<img src="/images/logo2.png" >
<div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a>

            </li>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #1</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #1 item #3</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">dropdown #2</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #2</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">dropdown #2 item #3</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content_area">
<p></p>
</div>
</div>
<DIV ID="footer">Hello and Welcome --------------</DIV>

<center>
<video width="900" height="550" controls >
<source src="fifa.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="fifa.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="fifa.webm" type="video/webm">
<object data="fifa.mp4" width="320" height="240">
<embed src="fifa.swf" width="320" height="240">
</object> 
</video>
</center>

</BODY>

</HTML>

CSS:

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
min-width:525px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 17px;
background-image:url('fifa2.jpg');
}

#header {
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
}

#footer {
float: left;
width: 100%;
background-color: #000000;
font-size: 14pt;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
left: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
padding-left: 200px;
padding-right: 125px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#left_side {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 200px;
right: 200px;
margin-left: -100%;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}

#right_side {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 125px;
background-color: #66CCCC;
margin-right: -125px;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}

#content_area {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 2000px;
margin-bottom: -2000px;
}


#nav {
background-color: #222;
}
#nav_wrapper {
width: 335px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
min-width: 200px;
}
#nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
color: #CCC;
display: block;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #333;
border: 5px solid #222;
border-top: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
color: #699;
}


video {
margin-top: 250px;
}


![My page][1]




Link to image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AARLw.jpg
```

Comment: The src of the image could be wrong, check that the image is located at /images/logo2.png

Comment: Please trim down your code and only show the relevant part of it for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set css position form image and video elements as:

```
img{
   position:absolute;
}

video{
   position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the path to the image. Almost always, when you see the little square but no image shows up, the path is wrong. Right click on the square, click on properties. Make sure your path (relative to where your HTML file is), is correct "case sensitive". BTW, if the file is ".PNG" that must also match, so instead of "logo2.png" you would have to use "logo2.PNG". verify all this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your image path from

```
<img src="/images/logo2.png" >
```

to

```
<img src="images/logo2.png" >
```